# Carregar dados de uma lista de um método no servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlet

Boa tarde pessoa!
Eu tenho esse método no servlet que retorna uma lista de valores.
Como eu faço para poder carregar os valores que ele possui, com jquery?

```
@WebServlet({"/ControleMovEstoque","/template/buscaMaterialExist.html","/template/cadEntradaEstq.html"})
public class ControleMovEstoque extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void verificaExistencia(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{

        String codigo = request.getParameter("codigo");
        String query = "select M from MovimentacaoEstoque M where M.codigo = " + codigo;
        List<MovimentacaoEstoque> listamovestoque = new MovimentacaoDao().existCadastrado(query);

        if (new MovimentacaoDao().existCadastrado(query).isEmpty()){
            request.setAttribute("modalEntrada", "<Strong>Este produto não está cadastrado no estoque</strong>");
        }
        else{
            request.setAttribute("modalEntrada", listamovestoque);
        }


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Tenho uma janela Modal que já paga alguns valores com jquery do html:

```
<td><a href="entradaMateriais"
    class="btn btn-xs btn-info entradaMateriais"
    data-toggle="modal" data-id="${list.id_material }" >Entrada</a> </td>
```

O jquery:

```
$(".entradaMateriais").on('click', function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id'); $("#fid").val(id);

            var nome =      $('#nome' + id).text();     $("#fnome").val(nome);
            var codigo =    $('#codigo' + id).text();       $("#fcodigo").val(codigo);
            var categoria = $('#categoria' + id).text();   $("#fcategoria").val(categoria);

            $("#entradaMateriais").modal();
        });
```

Na tela abaixo, já consigo carregar o que tenho no html, só falta as informações, marcadas em vermelho, que quero pegar do servlet.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vou tentar te ajudar.
Pra resolver seu problema, vamos destrinchar em pequenos problemas:

1. Identificar o que você quer retornar
2. Identificar qual o formato que você vai retornar
3. Criar a lógica para retorno
4. Tratar no JavaScript

**IDENTIFICAR O QUE VOCÊ QUER RETORNAR**

Primeiramente, não está presente no seu código se você esta realmente saindo da `servlet` para algum lugar. Não da pra identificar seu objeto `HttpServletResponse` enviando um `.redirect()` ou `.getWriter().print()`. Também não da pra identificar se você ta dando um  `.getRequestDispatcher().forward()` com seu objeto `HttpServletRequest`.

Vamos assumir a partir de agora que você decidiu enviar o retorno via objeto `HttpServletResponse` (É muito mais lógico e conveniente usar este objeto, uma vez que você está trabalhando com requisições `AJAX` e não quer recarregar uma página inteira)

Se código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
protected void verificaExistencia(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  try{
    String codigo = request.getParameter("codigo");
    String query = "select M from MovimentacaoEstoque M where M.codigo = " + 
      codigo;
    List<MovimentacaoEstoque> listamovestoque = new 
      MovimentacaoDao().existCadastrado(query);
    String retorno;
    if (listamovestoque.isEmpty()){
      retorno = "Produto não cadastrado";
    } else{
      retorno = "ok";
    }    
 } catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 /*Lógica para realizar o retorno*/
```

*Note que você também estava executando o `DAO` duas vezes. Uma pra pegar a lista de MovimentacaoEstoque e outra para verificar se era vazio. Não é necessário fazer isso, basta verificar utilizando o objeto da Lista.*

Bom, agora que você já sabe (ou não) se tem uma lista de movimentação, vamos para o passo 2.

**IDENTIFICAR QUAL O FORMATO QUE VOCÊ VAI RETORNAR**

Apenas uma palavra, **JSON**. 
É claro que você pode decidir qual formato melhor se adequa para seus requisitos, mas te adianto que **JSON** (quase) sempre irá funcionar para tudo. É leve, fácil de manipular e você consegue tratar com `JavaScript` com uma única linha de código.

Vamos assumir que você vai retornar em `JSON`. Nós vamos utilizar uma lib do Google chamada [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).
A lib *GSON* ajuda você a transformar seus Objetos Java em JSON. Dai fica bem facinho pra poder retornar.

A estrutura do seu JSON vai ser a seguinte.

- MENSAGEM
- CONTEUDO

Apenas essas duas já é o suficiente. Então vamos para o passo 3.

**CRIAR A LÓGICA PARA RETORNO**

Nós vamos primeiro transformar a lista retornada do banco em JSON fazendo assim:

```
Gson g = new Gson(); //cria um objeto gson
JsonObject g = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(listamovestoque); //você terá um json com sua lista de movimentacao de estoque.
g.addProperty("mensagem", retorno); //adiciona o retorno
String json = g.toString(); //aqui você tem seu json prontinho pra ser enviado
```

Basta enviar o retorno utilizando o método `.getWriter().print()` da classe `HttpServletResponse`.

```
response.getWriter().print(json);
```

Nosso *backend* ta pronto, vamos ao tratamento em JavaScript, ou passo 4.

**TRATAR NO JAVASCRIPT**

Notei que você ta usando `JQuery` então ficará ainda mais fácil.
Vamos fazer nossa requisição `AJAX` para recuperar os dados que precisamos.

```
$("sua-app/template/buscaMaterialExist.html", {
  data: {id: id},
  success: function(retorno){
    var resposta = retorno;
    console.log(resposta); //aqui terá o retorno do backend
  }
});
```

Notei também que você tem algum conhecimento em *JS*, então deve estar fácil de entender esse código.
Você vai perceber que o log da resposta vai ser um objeto *JavaScript* contendo 2 atributos.

- O primeiro, a mensagem lá do *backend*, que pode ser "ok" ou "Produto
  não cadastrado".
- O segundo é um *array* de objetos, onde cada objeto uma movimentacao de
  estoque igual do *backend*, que pode estar vazio.

Agora basta manipular esses dados para colocar nos campos que você deseja.

Espero muito que você consiga entender o fluxo. Qualquer dúvida poste nos comentários.